# is there a program that exists that can sync movies being watched across a network?

Tags: request

Have a host control the movie, and the clients will be synced up with everyone in the swarm, they would have the exact movie file on the machine already, just want to be to talk over voice chat about the movie, and be on the same page

Comment: this question needs alot of editing , but as far as i can understand its not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such program. To accomplish this. I would suggest having one user stream the movie and everyone watch that stream, including the user streaming it so everyone is on the same page within a few seconds.

I believe VLC supports media streams, if not [Procaster](http://www.livestream.com/userguide/index.php?title=Procaster) will work for things other than media files.